Usage of edge-triggering constructs in Verilog
I want to know if following code is syntactically, synthesiszably correct? Is it a recommended practice, if not, why? Assuming that count is a register which is updated in the same clock domain.
My argument is that even when we do always @ (posedge clk), the clk is also a wire, just like any other net type in Verilog.
wire trigger0;

assign trigger0 = (count > 5) ? 1 : 0;

always @ (posedge trigger0) begin
   // Some code
end 


You can do that in ASIC design, where you have free reign to place gates that implement your netlist. You cannot do that in an FPGA, which has constraints on which signals can be connected to the edge-sensitive (clock) input of a FF.

Did not know that FPGAs have constraints which impose restriction on what kind of signal can be connected to the edge sensitive input of a FF. Could you point me to specific vendor docs as source to this info?

Typically, LE outputs have a fanout limit of about four, which does not work for clock and reset signals, so there are separate high-fanout nets that have a single entry point and a tree structure with buffers that makes clock edges arrive somewhat simultaneously everywhere. Because the normal routing has such a low fanout, there are very few cases where routing a non-clock signal to a clock input makes sense, so most fabrics don't support it -- instead you are supposed to use the same clock everywhere, and switch the enable signal if you want a FF to keep its value.

Also, the edge sensitivity of a FF is implemented by chaining a low-active and a high-active stage. This order is fixed, so only positive edges can be detected, and there are minimum times for both low and high phases of the clock input. Some fabrics have routing resources that allow you to bring a normal signal into a clock network, but these connections will be placed near the edge, so you need to route the signal to the edge and back through a set of buffers, leading to a massive delay. That causes pretty much any edge triggered action on a non-clock signal to fail timing.

"Some fabrics have routing resources that allow you to bring a normal signal into a clock network", any docs on how to do this altera?

For the most part, you just pretend the resources exist and let synthesis find a mapping. Usually, no "good" mapping exists, because clock networks have high latency even if the destination is nearby, because they are built around "equal latency to all destinations" as a requirement.

As @toolic says, this is not great as it will infer that trigger is a clock signal, which generally speaking in synchronous logic design is not what you want - you're essentially creating a whole new asynchronous clock domain with a source that has all the pitfalls of asynchronous designs (glitches, race conditions, propagation delays).
Assuming that the "some code" is also intended to be synchronous to the same clock as count, then you can use a clocked block for some code enabled by a trigger:
always @ (posedge clock) begin
    if (trigger) begin // see discussion below
        // some code
    end
end

However, while this will ensure correct synchronous behaviour, it isn't edge sensitive. So you will also need to either add an edge detector by comparing with a delayed copy of the trigger, or if the counter increases every cycle, use an equal rather than greater than.
It will also add one clock cycle of latency, so change the trigger line to look for count being one less to assert the trigger a cycle early.
For monotonic counter:
assign trigger = (count == 5);

Or if the counter is not monotonically increasing, the edge detector version:
reg triggerDly;
assign trigger = (count >= 5);
always @ (posedge clock) begin
    triggerDly <= trigger
    if (trigger && !triggerDly) begin
        // some code
    end
end


suppose the count is getting value from a synchronous domain/clock triggered procedural always block, unless the clock domain is different, why would trigger0 have glitches?

@lousycoder nothing happens at exactly the same time in reality. If say the MSB of count updates a fraction of a clock cycle sooner than the other bits, then when your counter increments from 3 to 4, the value will briefly look like: "011 -> 111 -> 100". The brief 7 in the middle would cause your block to be triggered on this transition even though ultimately count is not greater than 5.

By using a clocked edge detector, you wait an entire clock cycle before checking the value of count==5, so assuming the glitch is less than a clock cycle, it is filtered away.

"011 -> 111 -> 100" is a classic example, Thanks!
Because clock signal is coming from (let's say) a PLL, is it less likely to be glitch prone?

@lousycoder It's not really to do with the clock source, but the routing and other logic delys. that cause the issue. So PLL vs other source doesn't change the advice

It is not a good design practice because there could be glitches on trigger0.  trigger0 is a combinational decode of several bits which will have slightly different delays from each other when synthesized into gates.
It would be better to  "register" this signal before using it as a clock signal, or use it as an "enable" signal:
always @(posedge clk)
    if (trigger0) // or detect the rising edge with another DFF


suppose the count is getting value from a synchronous domain/clock triggered procedural always block, unless the clock domain is different, why would trigger0 have glitches?

@lousycoder: I already explained the reason in the answer: "slightly different delays from each other when synthesized into gates".  Verilog is an HDL which abstracts away many of the details of an actual logic circuit.  You always need to keep in mind the schematic diagram of what you are describing, plus the physical layout of the flip-flops, AND gates, etc., along with the delays associated with their metal line connections.

Agreed. Thank you!
